# $z/\sqrt{-z^2}=-i$ when $\operatorname{arg}(z)\leq 0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, branch-cuts

Looking at [asymptotic expansions for the imaginary error function](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Erfi/06/02/) I find the following for $z\in\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$:
$$
\tag{1}
\frac{z}{\sqrt{-z^2}}=
\begin{cases}
-i, &\operatorname{arg}(z)\leq 0\\
i, &\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
**Is this correct? How is this derived from first principles? Can we state this without the use of cases, e.g. $z/\sqrt{-z^2}=\operatorname{sign}(\operatorname{arg}(z))i$?**

---

**My thoughts:**

If this holds for $z\in\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$ then it certainly holds for the special case $z\in\Bbb R\setminus \{0\}$. Assuming the case where $z$ is real we could write
$$
\tag{2}
\frac{z}{\sqrt{-z^2}}=\frac{z}{i\sqrt{z^2}}=\frac{z}{i|z|}=-\operatorname{sign}(z)i,
$$
but this does not agree with $(1)$ as it has the wrong sign. Clearly I'm missing something here.  Maybe we have to properly define the branch cut for $\sqrt\cdot$ and specify $\operatorname{arg}(z)\in(-\pi,\pi]$?

**Edit:**

According to WA (which presumably uses same branch cut as Mathematica)

$$
\begin{array}{cc}
z &z/\sqrt{-z^2}\\
1 &-i\\
1+i &i\\
i &i\\
-1+i &i\\
-1 &i\\
-1-i &-i\\
-i &-i\\
1-i &-i
\end{array}
$$

Comment: What is $sign(z)$ for a complex number?

Comment: @PaulFrost $sign$ is only applied to arg and to the case of real $z.$

Comment: Okay, I didn't read "If $z\in\Bbb R\setminus \{0\}$" ...

Comment: But didn't OP specify that $z \in \mathbb R$?

Comment: Your final sentence contains the key: You cannot answer this question from first principles without first properly defining the branch cut and the range of values for $\text{arg}(z)$. And for that, you'll have to ask Wolfram.

Comment: @AaronHendrickson The Wolfram site is not the best source when it comes to multivalued functions. I once had an argument with Oleg Marichev on this. I can give you a rigorous description of the asymptotics of erfi that takes into account the Stokes phenomenon if requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long as a comment.

1. Using the branch cut $(-\infty,0)$ and letting $z\in\mathbb
       C{\setminus}\{0\},$ $$\frac{z}{\sqrt{-z^2}}=
       \begin{cases} -i, &\displaystyle \operatorname{Arg}(z)\leq0\\
       i, &\text{otherwise} \tag{1}\end{cases}$$ is correct.
2. Your suggested compression under $(1)$ doesn't apply for positive
   numbers, as its output in this case is $0.$
3. $(2)$ is definitely correct, and does agree with $(1).$
4. By continuing to define $\operatorname{Arg}(z)$ on $(-\pi,\pi],$
   but the radical $\sqrt{\quad}$ to instead output the square root
   with the smallest nonnegative argument, $(1)$ becomes $$\frac{z}
   {\sqrt{-z^2}}= \begin{cases} -i, &\displaystyle-
   \frac\pi2\leq\operatorname{Arg}
   (z)<\frac\pi2\\ i, &\text{otherwise}. \tag{1*}\end{cases}$$